# How to append GET parameters to the link_to_route function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is it possible to add get parameters to a named route in laravel?

I have the following code in my `routes.php` file

```
Route::controller('store', 'StoreController',
    array(
        'getSearch' => 'store.search'
    )
);
```

I want to construct a link such as `domain.com/store/search?keyword=rolex` using the `link_to_route` function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get really close url with '/' after `search` so instead of:

`domain.com/store/search?keyword=rolex`

you can get:

`domain.com/store/search/?keyword=rolex`

What you need in this case is:

```
link_to_route('store.search', 'Search', array('keyword' => '?keyword=rolex'))
```

but it will change `?` into `%3F` so you should probably use in this case:

```
urldecode(link_to_route('store.search', 'Search', array('keyword' => '?keyword=rolex')))
```

Answer (score 2):

link_to_route takes a third argument, parameters.
So you can try to do this:

```
 link_to_route('store.search', 'Search', array('keyword' => 'rolex'))
```

Comment: Can you post the output from ```php artisan routes``` please?

Comment: `|        | GET|HEAD store/search/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                  | store.search                   | StoreController@getSearch                   |                |               |`